# set opacity of background color of div that works in ie7

Tags: html, css

I want to set opacity of background of div. Means i want transparent background of div. It is very simple for browsers like chrome & firefox because rgba is supported.

But for ie7, i don't know how to do that. "filter: alpha(opacity=50);" is not useful to me, because i want transparent background, not content.

I also don't want transparent image to be set as background.

I have also tried ::before and apply "filter: alpha(opacity=50);", but it is also not working in ie.

Thank You.

Comment: I think you just have to tile a semi-transparent image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a transparent image for the background for IE. It's annoying but it's the best way of doing what you want without getting stuck with opacity on the text. Or just [go mental with the filters](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/)...

```
.opacityTest{
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

Comment: To the OP: Just be forewarned that filters present a serious performance hit in IE. I think SpaceBeers' first suggestion of a transparent image is your best bet, overall.

Comment: @chipcullen - agreed. It's the simplest option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
div
{
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use a transparent background image for IE LTE < 7 (with some conditional comment/css)