# rgba not compatible with IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, compatibility, rgba

In my CSS codes, I am changing the background using rgba :

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

It is working well on every browser but not on IE7 where the background seems simply to be transparent.

Anything I can do to make it works with IE7 ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688462/set-opacity-of-background-color-of-div-that-works-in-ie7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a fallback for IE7 since it's not working in IE8 and below (http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba())

```
div {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
```